# Winsorize data by column in R using the Winsorize function

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 739 variables and I want to winsorize within each variable (i.e. column).

```
library(DescTools)
```

Using the below code, the data are winsorized using the entire data frame. Since I cannot manually winsorize each column, is there are way to apply this function within column?

```
EEG_w<-Winsorize(EEG[3:739], minval = NULL, maxval = NULL, probs = c(0.05, 0.95),  na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50142807/winsorizing-across-all-columns-in-a-data-frame-r-using-lapply

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `Winsorize` column by column using `apply`.

```
EEG_w<-apply(EEG, 2, Winsorize, na.rm = TRUE)
```